# Transforming a continuous function into a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Given a continuous function $f(x)$ when does there exist a non-constant continuous function $g(x)$ such that $f(g(x))$ is differentiable what about $g(f(x))$?

Does there exist any examples of $f(x)$ such that no such $g(x)$ exist for either of the transformations ?
*In this paper*- 
 Bruckner, A. M. “Creating Differentiability and Destroying Derivatives.” The American Mathematical Monthly, vol. 85, no. 7, 1978, pp. 554–562. JSTOR, [www.jstor.org/stable/2320863](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2320863).  
A characterisation for $g(x)$ being a homeomorphism is given .

It is easy to construct examples for where no such $g(x)$ exists if it is restricted to a homeomorphism using nowhere differentiable functions .

Comment: Can you give some context for your question? This sounds a bit like homework from the way it is asked.

Comment: In what terms do you want your characterizations to be expressed? For any condition $C$, the tautological characterization is always available: $C$ holds iff $C$ holds. So, without specifying the terms, your problems lose meaning.

Comment: @IosifPinelis If one wants to characterise the derivative simply saying F is a derivative if there exists G such that G’ = F is enough but this does not reveal anything new about derivatives . But Derivatives have interesting properties such as they are baire 1  and they can’t be discontinuous everywhere etc. The tautology can’t be accepted as it does not reveal much (except the definition) about the structure of derivatives

Comment: Proposition 1 in the paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1337001388 shows that moving a quantifier in the definition of the KH integrability provides a characterization of derivatives. However, I don't think this characterization is very useful: just as the definition of a derivative function (saying there **exists** an anti-derivative function), the mentioned characterization contains the non-constructive condition of the **existence** of a (gauge) function.

Comment: Of course, a tautology is completely useless. That is why you need to specify the terms of a characterization.

Comment: @IosifPinelis In this paper-  Bruckner, A. M. “Creating Differentiability and Destroying Derivatives.” The American Mathematical Monthly, vol. 85, no. 7, 1978, pp. 554–562. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/2320863. Accessed 14 Sept. 2020.  A characterisation for g(x) being a homeomorphism is given .

Comment: @IosifPinelis I edited the question for examples also.